# How to use open command in linux shell properly?

Tags: linux, shell

I want to open a C program /Users/abc/Desktop/thread_sock.

```
localhost:~ abc$ /Users/abc/Desktop/thread_sock 2 1
```

2and1 is my parameters.
but now I want to use open command.so I type

```
localhost:~ abc$ open /Users/abc/Desktop/thread_sock 2 1.
```

but it failed.
The result is

```
The files /Users/abc/2 and /Users/abc/1 do not exist.
```

i have also tried

```
localhost:~ abc$ open /Users/abc/Desktop/thread_sock --args 2 1.
```

like what 'man open' says.but it failed.So boaring.....it looks so easy.but i cant solve it.....what is the right format？？？？？

Comment: There is no built-in `open` command in the linux shell - it is, in all probability a helper tool for the GUI environment you're using. What it's doing is trying to open each of the items passed as a file and can't find some of them

Comment: It's probably something like an alias being used see - http://superuser.com/questions/38984/linux-equivalent-command-for-open-command-on-mac-windows

Comment: when you say `open`, do you mean `run`?

Comment: @user1676978 really are you trying to open a file or executing the program ???what you are trying to do?

Comment: @TZHX um,run and pass the parameters to thread_sock.I can success running as "/Users/abc/Desktop/thread_sock 2 1".it pass 2 and 1 to thread_sock.but when I use open it failed....

Comment: What does opening a binary executable means to you? On Linux, executables are usually executed (by `execve(2)` syscall), not opened... To execute your program in a shell you could type its full path, e.g. type just `/Users/abc/Desktop/thread_sock 2 1` in your terminal.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax should be (from memory)

```
$ /Users/abc/Desktop/thread_sock 2 1
```

Just giving the path to the binary file should run it.

Comment: @TZHXif i want to use OPEN command.what should I do??

Comment: I really doubt that the `open` command is what you actually want, but in that case, just use `open` without the `2 1`.

Comment: when you type "man open".it shows open [-e] [-t] [-f] [-F] [-W] [-R] [-n] [-g] [-h] [-b bundle_identifier] [-a application] file ... [--args arg1 ...].Notice the last one.it can pass parameters in fact.I means what is the right format.

Comment: What do you mean by `open`-ing a binary executable?????

Answer (score 1):

Please check the [man page of open command](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdln_open.htm), it may help you.

Comment: I want to use OPEN command in shell.but not open functions.Do you know that?

Comment: I run 'man open'.And It shows like this    open [-e] [-t] [-f] [-F] [-W] [-R] [-n] [-g] [-h] [-b bundle_identifier]
          [-a application] file ... [--args arg1 ...]  I want to know how to use [--args arg1 ...]???

Answer (score 0):

To open a C program file in linux

```
     localhost:~ abc$ vim /Users/abc/Desktop/thread_sock.c
```

You can use `vim,view ,less` commands can use in terminal

To run a file :

```
     localhost:~ abc$ /Users/abc/Desktop/thread_sock 2 1
```

Comment: @ThangaIn fact,thread_sock is .out file.I have compile it.I just want to use open command to open it.do you know how??

Comment: It has no sense to open an executable.

Comment: @ Basile Starynkevitch yeah i do know about that doesn make sense , user were confused with the question :)